# Are ring-shaped protection plates made?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, studs

I know of the flat stud guards for pipes plumbed through studs, but do they have metal ring versions you could place inside the hole in the stud instead?

Main reason I am asking is because if I run plumbing through an interior wall, I would need stud guards on both sides (?) which means I need to remove the drywall on both sides.

Or maybe there is another way to prevent the need to remove the drywall from both sides?

Comment: Steel plates(stud guards) are required when cables/plumbing closer than an 1 and 1/2 inch from the edge.  If you need one on each side, then the hole is probably too big for the stud.  How would you security attach a round steel ring inside of a stud?

Comment: Ahh i didnt know there was a min distance. So that means anything bigger than 1/2 needs a stud guard for standard 2x4. Still kind of scary because i have used 2 and 1/2 screws into a stud, but now i know thats possiblly dangerous.

Comment: Also, for such a steel ring I imagine a male and female threading with one for each side to secure it into the hole.

Comment: If this is remodel where you would be leaving original finished wall on one side, then I doubt that you would be required to remove that finished wall just to add protective plates for plumbing passing through studs. If approval requires nailing plates, you could make holes and then patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do something for this situation, then try this: Get some one-inch steel electrical conduit or other thin walled pipe and cut some inch and a half lengths. Drill 1 or 2 holes near the cut ends for a finishing nail or small screw. Drill the studs then insert your steel guards into each hole and secure them. You now have steel lined holes. If the studs are load-bearing, you can add sister studs and use longer steels.